# Share Links/Images on Facebook with React-Native

Tags: facebook, react-native, fbsdk

I'm using `react-native-fbsdk` for FB login and share features.

I want to let the users post things on their FB profile.

Problem is, the only way I found to add text to Links/Images is the `caption` attribute. All others like `quote` or `contentDescription` don't work, but FB forbids to write pre-defined text in the captions.

How do I get a link or an image onto Facebook via the SDK that shows custom text?

Example 1:

I share an image via SDK: I can only add a `caption` which has to be written by the user

Example 2:

I share a link via SDK: Almost all fields a deprecated, only `quote` is left, but it doesn't show up on FB after I shared a link to an image.

Comment: what do you mean? custom text must be 100% written by the user. just use the caption field. please be more specific and add your code, this is way too broad for stackoverflow right now, i´m afraid.

Comment: What I mean is, when I see people post stuff on FB, there is a title and a description AND their custom text. the title and the description comes from the app/website the caption comes from the user. When I post something I only get an image and URL but no text shows up.

Comment: title and description is for links and the information comes from the og tags. make sure you know the difference between sharing a link (with existing og tags and a message) and uploading a photo (with a caption). message and caption must be 100% user generated.

Comment: Ah, so it's a thing of the website and not the FBSDK? okay, thanks.